# CSS: Min-height min-content doesn't work with height vh-100

Tags: html, css

I want to have a box fill the whole page, but if the content of the box exceeds the viewport, I want to show scrollbars on the body (not the box).

I tried using min-height and height properties.

```
.vh-adaptable {
  min-height: min-content;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

The min-height statement seems to have not effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The box can only fill it's parent, so you need to set the height there. Difficult to answer this without knowing the entire context.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the height and then give the property

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That doesn't help, since it puts scrollbars on the box, not the body. I've clarified my question.